# how can I use sed or awk to correct a log time format

Tags: file, bash, csv, sed, awk

I am currently working on a script which processes a csv file, and corrects certain aspects of them along the way. One of the things that it does is correct time format if needed. Two type of conversion takes place:

```
 xx:xx:xx to PTxxHxxMxxS
 10:03:45 to PT10H03M45S
```

I've have been able to do this using the following (see below) although I am trying to find out how to do it either using sed or awk in order to speed up the process. In addition to the actual conversion process, I would also like to keep count of the changes that are made (so say 4 times values are converted, a counter would be incremented to 4), which I have been able to do easily with the if statement below (though it is not shown), although I would not know much about doing that using sed/awk.

```
 istimef=$( echo "$Sfcpp6" | grep ".*:.*:.*" )
                    if [ "$istimef" != "" ]; then
                            hs=$( echo "$Sfcpp6" | cut -d ':' -f 1 )
                            mn=$( echo "$Sfcpp6" | cut -d ':' -f 2 )
                            sc=$( echo "$Sfcpp6" | cut -d ':' -f 3 )
                            Sfcpp6=$( echo "PT"$hs"H"$mn"M"$sc"S" )
                            echo "$Sfcp6"
                    fi
```

which essentially checks if the time value is even there, and then performs the conversion.

Comment: It's a good idea to provide sample input (at least a couple of lines) and output in such questions (even though this question is clear as is).

Comment: @LevLevitsky oops sorry about that, should have made the example for clear

Comment: look up bash substring manipulation sometime, it is really handy - to replace the echo | grep use: `${varname:0:2}` `${varname:2:2}` `${varname:5:2}`

Comment: @technosaurus thanks! will have to check that out, anything to shave off time lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` solution: uses `\(...\)` to capture the numbers, character classes `[0-9]` to match any digit.

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/PT\1H\2M\3S/'
```

Comment: worked perfectly, thanks! one question though, would it be possible to make sed keep count of the changes that It has made? for instance increment a counter or something of the sort when it changes a time value

Comment: you could predetermine the number by grepping for the pattern and piping it to wc

Answer (score 2):

It amazing how much processes and subshells you need for this task! I'll always be amazed at people's ingenuity and creativity. I counted 10 subshells, and 4 process spawns.

Look, you can achieve exactly the same without spawning one process and with no subshell whatsoever. We're talking about speed-up here!

First task, given a string in the form `xx:yy:zz`, transform it into `PTxxHyyMzzS` as efficiently as possible (look, in only one command! and a builtin! no `sed`!):

```
$ string='12:34:56'
$ printf -v transformed 'PT%sH%sM%sS' ${string//:/ }
$ # Done! Don't believe me?
$ echo "$transformed"
PT12H34M56S
```

Now, before doing this, you probably want to check if the string is of the form `xx:yy:zz`. Quit `grep` for that. Just test it thus:

```
if [[ "$string" = *:*:* ]]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

So the part of your script you showed us would be much more efficient thus:

```
if [[ "$Sfcpp6" = *:*:* ]]; then
    printf -v Sfcp6 'PT%sH%sM%sS' ${Sfcpp6//:/ }
    echo "$Sfcp6"
fi
```

Total: 0 subshells, 0 processes spawned.

Or if your goal is only to echo the transformed string:

```
if [[ "$Sfcpp6" = *:*:* ]]; then
    printf 'PT%sH%sM%sS\n' ${Sfcpp6//:/ }
fi
```

Comment: +1 for taking time for long explanations, good advices & humour

Comment: thanks! have actually been working on a final project for a course which involves taking in three sources of data (2 xls files and one xml in this case), cleansing/correcting the data, and then outputting the data to a mysql server. the prof had suggested php although I had decided to go with cgi pages (bash ones) and have an additional script that took care of the file processing. my first version of the script took around 7 seconds to complete, but after redoing the code based on all of the questions i have been asking, I was able to get it down to just above 1 second on average :)

Comment: if you would like to see the final product itself, simply download this zip file http://eatmyrice.org/FZIP.zip which contains the two xls files and the xml file, and then go to this url http://eatmyrice.org/xmlparse.html which has a file upload form, upload the zip and press submit, after which it does its thing, and finally displays so stats at the end along with a .csv version of the final results (uploads them to mysql as well, although I would prefer to keep that access private), let me know what you think if you decide to try it out, very happy with the results here

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the substituted lines :

```
perl -pe '
    END{print "count=$count\n"}
    s/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/PT$1H$2M$3S/ && $count++
' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The GNU awk equivalent of this sed solution posted by @choroba:

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)/PT\1H\2M\3S/'
```

would be the very similar:

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/,"PT\\1H\\2M\\3S","")}'
```

but the awk solution can be trivially modified to address your question of "would it be possible to make sed keep count of the changes that It has made?":

```
awk '{orig=$0; $0=gensub(/([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/,"PT\\1H\\2M\\3S",""); print} $0 != orig{count++} END{printf "%d changes made.\n",count}'
```

while the sed solution can't.